# Module Not Found Error - Importing from sibling directory

Tags: python, python-import

So I have tried many solutions found on stack overflow but am still having issues.

Below is my project structure.

```
project
    | tool1
       | - application.py
    | resources
       | - tools
          | - dao.py
```

Within application.py I have the following import statement:

```
from resources.tools.dao import DAO
```

This works fine in PyCharm, but when I try to run it from the command line from the project directory (`python tool1/application.py`), I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources'
```

I get the same error if I move into 'tool1' folder and run: `python application.py`

I have tried adding .. before the imports, setting different folders as my source root folder through PyCharm, and adding blank `__init__.py` files to the resources directory.

Why is PyCharm able to find 'resources' but the command line is not? How can I change this so that my solution works from either location?

If it helps, I am using Python 3.7 and Windows. I am open to restructuring the project directory, but there are going to be multiple tools/applications that will all use dao.py and the other tools in the resources directory, so resources should be at least as high level as the other projects.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: multiple good answers below. ended up using something most similar to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you created __ init __.py in each directory. You could add to system path. 
It should import dao from anywhere. It works in linux for sure.

```
# tool1.__init__.py
import sys
import os

CURRPATH, TAIL = os.path.split(os.getcwd())
while CURRPATH != "/":
    if TAIL == 'project':
        if os.path.join(CURRPATH, TAIL) not in sys.path:
            sys.path.append(os.path.join(CURRPATH, TAIL))
        break
    CURRPATH, TAIL = os.path.split(CURRPATH)
from resources.tools.dao import DAO
```

and in application.py

```
# tool1.application.py
from __init__ import DAO
```

Comment: This worked for me, it just doesn't seem too elegant because you have to go into the __init__ to see exactly where the dao is. I would prefer if I could somehow do from resources.tools.dao import DAO. Do you know of a tweak to accomplish that? ?

Comment: Just copy code from __init__ into application.py and eliminate  "from __init__..."

Comment: too involved. some of the other answers may be less of an eye-sore

Answer (score 1):

Run the script using the `-m` argument. i.e.

`python -m project.tool1.application`

This makes the script run with the `project` package in the namespace. (You may need to add an `__init__.py` file to `project` to make it a package)

Answer (score 0):

If project is your root directory (i.e. you have initialized pythonpath to this directory), then you need to import modules like this:

```
from project.resources.tools.dao import DAO
```

Comment: is there an elegant way to initialize the pythonpath to the root folder programmatically?

Comment: yes, you have to run : export PYTHONPATH=Your_root_folder:$PYTHONPATH. This will set your project under python paths.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to declare the parent directory path could be:

```
import os, sys

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent_dir_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, os.pardir))
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir_path)
```

And then this line would work without issues:

```
from resources.tools.dao import DAO
```